# What is the difference of the package under `anaconda3/bin` and `anaconda3/lib/python3.7/`?

Tags: pip, package, conda

After I install the package **transformer** by `pip install transformer`, I find it under three locations.

```
    /home/jinggu/anaconda3/bin/transformers
    /home/jinggu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers-2.1.1.dist-info/*
    /home/jinggu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/*
```

What is the difference between these three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two in `site-packages` are for the metadata about the package (`transformers-2.1.1.dist-info/`) and the actual source code (`transformers/`). The file in the `bin/` folder is called [an entry point](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/) and represents a commandline interface provided by the package. In this case, you can see this defined in [the `setup.py` file](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3ddce1d74cda5be47704381e657ee22ce5a5fc7b/setup.py#L61) and that it points to running [the `main()` function](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3ddce1d74cda5be47704381e657ee22ce5a5fc7b/transformers/__main__.py#L2).

Answer (score 1):

The `anaconda3/bin` folder contains executables installed w/ the package. If packages would like to provide a command line interface they will come with binaries to be executed from the command line. Not sure what transformers is, but if you navigate to `anaconda3/bin/` you should be able to `./transformers -flags or cla's`.

The `python3.7/site-packages/` folders contain the python source code that can be imported to be used in your projects. This is generally how anaconda packages are used  - and how you use the packaged libraries through conda's environment.

In your case, the transformers package came with binaries as well as the source code (to be `imported` for use in your projects).